# Multiplayer functionality via Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, multiplayer

I want to add multiplayer functionality in my game via Facebook . So that Facebook friends can play game together using multiplayer. I implemented it via google play services but how can I implement it via Faceboook?

Comment: You can refer to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial

Comment: really, how can anyone UPVOTE this question? it´s WAY too broad...

Comment: Sometimes you need help with broad programming issues.